# Apply MinMaxScaler() on a pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the sklearn MinMaxScaler to rescale a python column like below:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
y = scaler.fit(df['total_amount'])
```

But got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/edamame/workspace/git/my-analysis/experiments/my_seq.py", line 54, in <module>
    y = scaler.fit(df['total_amount'])
  File "/Users/edamame/workspace/git/my-analysis/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 308, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y)
  File "/Users/edamame/workspace/git/my-analysis/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 334, in partial_fit
    estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
  File "/Users/edamame/workspace/git/my-analysis/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 441, in check_array
    "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[3.180000e+00 2.937450e+03 6.023850e+03 2.216292e+04 1.074589e+04
   :
 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 9.000000e+01 1.260000e+03].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Any idea what was wrong?

Comment: `.reshape(rows_num, -1)` or `.reshape(rows_num, 1)` to fit dataframes with many rows

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The input to [MinMaxScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) needs to be array-like, with `shape [n_samples, n_features]`. So you can apply it on the column as a *dataframe* rather than a *series* (using double square brackets instead of single):

```
y = scaler.fit(df[['total_amount']])
```

Though from your description, it sounds like you want `fit_transform` rather than just `fit` (but I could be wrong):

```
y = scaler.fit_transform(df[['total_amount']])
```

---

**A little more explanation:**

If your dataframe had 100 rows, consider the difference in shape when you transform a column to an array:

```
>>> np.array(df[['total_amount']]).shape
(100, 1)

>>> np.array(df['total_amount']).shape
(100,)
```

The first returns a shape that matches `[n_samples, n_features]` (as required by MinMaxScaler), whereas the second does not.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do with this way:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

x = df.values #returns a numpy array
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
df = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
```